# Making bread in a bread maker using regular yeast not bread maker yeast

Tags: substitutions

With Fleischmann's bread yeast, how much regular yeast in a packet is required for a recipe calling for a packet of breadmaker yeast?

We have three at least different kinds of Fleischmann's yeast - one for bread dough makers, and two others - I had one of the others and had no way to tell - the bread came out dense.

Comment: Hello Kate, I don't understand exactly what you are asking. What is "not bread dough yeast"?

Comment: @rumtscho This might be a cultural difference but in America, there are packets of instant yeast made specifically for bread makers. I think Kate is asking how to substitute other type of yeast for a single packet of this bread maker yeast.

Comment: Fleishmann's markets bread machine yeast, active dry yeast, rapid-rise dry yeast, fresh active yeast, and pizza dough yeast. You can use any of these to make bread. http://www.breadworld.com/products Exactly which yeast do you consider "regular"? If you want to use active dry yeast instead of bread machine yeast, you can. I believe that is covered in other questions.

Comment: Use the same amount of yeast. — When I was learning to make bread and still used a machine, I tried all of the different brands and "flavors" of yeast sold in pre-measured foil packets. There were probably subtle differences, but they all seemed to work about the same to me. So called "bread machine" yeast might be a little faster acting, but I think you'll be just as successful using "regular" yeast.

Comment: As per your edit, you may have better luck if you proof the yeast. Heat a small amount (1/4 cup or so) of the liquid to just warm (~105F, ~40.5C) and stir in the yeast. Add it to the bread maker after it gets foamy, which should just take a few minutes. If it doesn't foam fairly vigorously, consider it bad and buy more yeast before proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

A packet of instant yeast is approximately 2 and 1/4 teaspoon of yeast.

Please note that instant yeast used in bread maker is slightly different from active dry yeast. Instant yeast will generally be much smaller granules and can be mixed directly with the dry ingredients without proofing. Active dry yeast will be larger granules and often times require proofing. However there are several brands that does not require this extra proofing step.

Note that not all instant yeast come in small packets. I have used [SAF Instant Yeast](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001CXUHW) with very good results.

Comment: I second your recommendation of buying SAF yeast by the pound — it's much less expensive than the foil packets, and easier to use only the amount you need. I keep mine in the freezer (in a glass jar), and it can last for more than a year.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully made bread in my bread machine using Fleischmann's Traditional Yeast, which is in the form of tiny balls that are much coarser than those of Bread Machine Yeast.  The main difference is that when using Traditional Yeast I mix it with the water and sugar and let it sit until it foams, and then stir it and put it into the pan.  I then add all of the other ingredients, mixing the salt with the flour and adding that last.